# Is there a unit testing capability with WebMatrix?

Tags: unit-testing, webmatrix

I'm looking for a definitive answer to the question, Does WebMatrix have a unit testing capability?  I've found other people questioning this, but haven't found anything definitive on the ASP.NET site or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. But you can request it and see how popular the feature would be by submitting it to the Microsoft Connect site for WebMatrix:

https://connect.microsoft.com/webmatrix/feedback/

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the answer, simtan.  I was fairly certain of that, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something